# Building a row from a dict in pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to dynamically build a row in pySpark 1.6.1, then build it into a dataframe.  The general idea is to extend the results of `describe` to include, for example, skew and kurtosis.  Here's what I thought should work:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

row_dict = {'C0': -1.1990072635132698,
            'C3': 0.12605772684660232,
            'C4': 0.5760856026559944,
            'C5': 0.1951877800894315,
            'C6': 24.72378589441825,
            'summary': 'kurtosis'}

new_row = Row(row_dict)
```

But this returns `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, dict found` which is a fairly clear error.  Then I found that if I defined the Row fields first, I *could* use a dict:

```
r = Row('summary', 'C0', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6')
r(row_dict)
> Row(summary={'summary': 'kurtosis', 'C3': 0.12605772684660232, 'C0': -1.1990072635132698, 'C6': 24.72378589441825, 'C5': 0.1951877800894315, 'C4': 0.5760856026559944})
```

Which would be a fine step, except it doesn't seem like I can dynamically specify the fields in `Row`.  I need this to work for an unknown number of rows with unknown names.  According to the documentation you can actually go the other way:

```
>>> Row(name="Alice", age=11).asDict() == {'name': 'Alice', 'age': 11}
True
```

So it seems like I should be able to do this.  It also appears there may be some deprecated features from older versions that allowed this, for example [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.Row-class.html).  Is there a more current equivalent I'm missing?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use keyword arguments unpacking as follows:

```
Row(**row_dict)

## Row(C0=-1.1990072635132698, C3=0.12605772684660232, C4=0.5760856026559944, 
##     C5=0.1951877800894315, C6=24.72378589441825, summary='kurtosis')
```

It is important to note that it [internally sorts data by key](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/480357cc6d71c682fe703611c71c1e6a36e6ce9a/python/pyspark/sql/types.py#L1374-L1375) to address [problems with older Python versions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/).

This behavior is likely to be removed in the upcoming releases - see [SPARK-29748](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29748) *Remove sorting of fields in PySpark SQL Row creation*. Once it is remove you'll have to ensure that the order of values in the `dict` is consistent across records.

Comment: Is this valid from a specific version of Python or is it a general rule ? The reason I'm asking is due to your [latest edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38253641/revisions).

Comment: @eliasah Since Spark will always sort internally, it just doesn't matter what we do before that. And given JIRA discussion it won't change until Spark drops support for  Python < 3.6 (not any time soon). `OrderedDict` was a bit misleading, hence I removed it.

Comment: @eliasah I believe that my first idea was to use `*args` (`Row` implements `__new__` and takes different path with positional arguments) not `**kwargs` constructors - this is why  I included sorting, and somehow it ended up in the answer.

Comment: @zero323 can this approach be used with python 2.7 version and nested Dictionary? My aim was to convert twitter DStream to Row RDD then to DF as I am usinf Spark 1.6 version.

Answer (score 7):

In case the dict is not flatten, you can convert dict to Row recursively.

```
def as_row(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        dictionary = {k: as_row(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
        return Row(**dictionary)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [as_row(v) for v in obj]
    else:
        return obj
```