# How to create Spark Row from list of key-value pairs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose I have got a list of key-value pairs:

```
kvs = [('x', 0), ('a', 1)]
```

Now I'd like to create a Spark `Row` from `kvs` with the same order of keys as in `kvs`.
How to do it in `Python` ?

Comment: convert I to dict and use Row(**kvs)

Comment: It does not preserve the order of the pairs.

Comment: you can use OrderedDict https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253385/building-a-row-from-a-dict-in-pyspark

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run it yet but may you check once I will edit after running if fails.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
kvs = [('x', 0), ('a', 1)]
h = {}
[h.update({k:v}) for k,v in kvs]
row = Row(**h)
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not preserve the order of the pairs in `kvs`,

Comment: Check how to preserve order using OrderedDict
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253385/building-a-row-from-a-dict-in-pyspark

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

Row(*[k for k, _ in kvs])(*[v for _, v in kvs])
```

but in my opinion it is better to avoid `Row` whatsoever. Other than being a convenient class to represent local values fetched from the JVM backend, it has no special meaning in Spark. In almost every context:

```
tuple(v for _, v in kvs)
```

is perfectly valid replacement for `Row`.